# Why do I need the permission READ_CONTACTS to read the call log?

Tags: android, android-securityexception

The App is reading the call log. On most devices that is fine, some others get `SecurityException` for `READ_CONTACTS` (which I don't have and don't want in my `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Why is that and can I do something about that? Perhaps through a projection, which does **not** fetch the `CACHED_NAME`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG` was introduced in API Level 16.  Before that, it was implicit in `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` and didn't exist as a separate permission. I suspect your trouble is with API 15 and lower devices since they will ignore your manifest's `uses-permission` line for `READ_CALL_LOG` and thus have no permission for reading the logs.  For those devices, `READ_CONTACTS` is the correct permission.

Comment: So, I used `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" android:maxSdkVersion="15" />` to avoid the need to ask for this permission in newer API's.

Comment: Just tried uploading my APK with this permission and maxSdkVersion="15", the console tells me the minimum maxSdkVersion should be 18!?

Comment: Setting a maxSdkVersion is a bad practice. Someone updates their phone and your app doesn't work anymore, just because you didn't implement stuff the way it should.

Comment: @Paul Ratazzi   If I want read phone book but don't want read call logs, what should I do?

Comment: @dragonfly If you are on API 16 or later (I would hope so at this point), just declare `READ_CONTACTS` permission  in your manifest. `READ_CALL_LOGS` is a separate permission.